# JWT Validation Authorization

Tags: php, encoding, jwt

please help,
I have a problem with my code, I tried to provide JWT Validation at login, replace Session Php, I managed to get a token when the user has sent an email and password which is validated with data in the database, but I have a problem after the user gets the token and will executes the next command, namely

> :Error: "kid" empty, unable to lookup correct key.

I know maybe because I haven't given an ID to every data that I have validated and retrieved from the database, but I'm confused and need your help, experience is a valuable value. Thank You.

```
<?php   
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';        
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use Firebase\JWT\Key;

class Session
{

    public function __construct(public string $username, public string $role)
    {
    }

}

class SessionManager
{

    public static string $SECRET_KEY = "ahwehahewaheksmdashdadjwadmawduaskahkk";

    public static function login(string $username, string $password): bool
    {   
        try {
            $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=assabil", "root", "");
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT Username, password_col FROM pengurus");
            $statement->execute();
            $row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if ($row && password_verify($password, $row['password_col'])) {
                $payload = [
                    'uid' => $id,
                    "Username" => $username,
                    "role" => "customer"
                ];
          
                $jwt = JWT::encode($payload, SessionManager::$SECRET_KEY, 'HS256');
                setcookie("A-SSB-SESSION", $jwt);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public static function getCurrentSession(): Session
    {
        if (isset($_COOKIE['A-SSB-SESSION'])) {
            $jwt = $_COOKIE['A-SSB-SESSION'];
            try {
                $payload = JWT::decode($jwt, SessionManager::$SECRET_KEY, ['HS256']);
                var_dump($payload); // Check the value of $payload
                return new Session($payload->Username, $payload->role);
            } catch (Exception $exception) {
                echo "Error: " . $exception->getMessage();
                die(); // Terminate the script to see the error message
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception("User is not login");
        }
    }
    
    
}


?>
```

I'm trying to find a solution regarding JWT Token validation, I hope you can get a solution.